# Using pandas dataframe, how do I compare the columns of a dataframe to the entries in an array?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, count

This is my code snippet:

```
# Define array entries
array = ['RegCreateKeyA', 'RegCreateKeyExA', 'RegCreateKeyExW', 'RegCreateKeyTransactedA', ...]
# Print rows that have the specifed APIs using location2 column  
rels = df.loc[df['location2'].isin(array)]
rel = rels.assign(Index = range(len(rels))).set_index('Index')
# Count number of times a process calls each API
count = rel.groupby(['Process_Name', 'location2']).size()
# convert from long to wide
temp = count.unstack()
print(temp)
```

Array contains over 100 entries. I compare the values in location2 column with array if it exists in array, I save to rels. Then count takes the frequency count of each of the entries in location2. It saves it in a long mode so I convert to wide and save it to temp then print that out.

The problem is that my code only prints out the count for entries in the array that it contains, I also want it to print out a count of zero for entries that it doesn't contain but I'm stumped on the best way to do that.

As stated the column header only contains values from the arrays that it contains but I want it to include all the entries from the array and have a value of zero for those that are not included in the dataframe.

[I've attached a screenshot of my output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QS2I.png)

Answer (score 0):

***try these codes***

```
array = ['RegCreateKeyA', 'RegCreateKeyExA', 'RegCreateKeyExW', 'RegCreateKeyTransactedA']
df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    "location2":['RegCreateKeyA', 'RegCreateKeyA', 'RegCreateKeyExA', 'RegCreateKeyExW', 'RegCreateKeyTransactedA', 1,2,3,"Match"],
    "Process_Name":['exa', 'exa', "exa", 'exw', 'ta', 1,2,3,"Match"]
})

df["Counts"] = df[["location2", "Process_Name"]].apply(lambda x: 1 if x["location2"] in array else np.nan, axis=1)

pivot = df.pivot_table(index="Process_Name", columns="location2", aggfunc="count").fillna(0).astype(int)
print(pivot)
```